# How to prevent script from running on html post

Tags: javascript, html

I am storing the contents of my blog as HTML in mySQL database in HTML format. I created a new post today which has a some script

```
<pre>
    <code class="language-javascript">
        <script>
            alert("HELLO!!");
        </script>
    </code>
</pre>
```

Inside my blog I wanted it to be displayed as:

```
 <script>
         alert("HELLO!!");
  </script>
```

But instead of that the script runs and messes up my blog. I am using jquery to append to my blog:

```
$(".blog-main-content").append(allArticles);
```

How do programming blogs prevent the script from running? Is it a good idea to store the contents as html? So far it as been a real pain.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your `<` like `&lt;`, then it will not be interpreted as html.

```js
var html = `<pre>
<code class="language-javascript">
  &lt;script>
    alert("HELLO!!");
  &lt;/script>
</code>
</pre>`;

$("div").append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```